# Ocultar valores nulos

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Hola estoy trabajando en Visual Studio con `C#`, quiero saber cómo solucionar este problema: `System.NullReferenceException` en `CapaPresentacion.exe`, me aparece porque intento ocultar una columna de un datagridview que tiene valores nulos, ¿cómo puedo solucionarlo?
Este es el codigo:

```
tablastock.DataSource = obj.TraerProducto("-10", Convert.ToInt32(txtBuscarP.Text));

tablaproducto.Columns["codigobarra"].Visible = false;
tablaproducto.Columns["id"].Visible = false;
```

Aclaro que el `datasource` funciona correctamente para llenar la tabla pero no se deberian poder ver las columnas que mencione, por eso las quiero ocultar

Comment: ¿En qué punto te aparece? ¿Estás intentado acceder a alguna de las columnas ocultas?

Comment: Me extraña mucho lo que comentas. Ocultar unas columnas en ningun caso debe lanzar esa excepción, con lo que es mas probable que se lance al asignar el datasource. Depura bien tu código para ver exactamente que está pasando.

Comment: Puede pasar porque ni el índice "codigobarra" o "id" existe, se necesitaría saber en que sitio exacto ocurre.

Comment: listo ya lo solucione, no se donde habra estado el error, volvi a hacer la consulta desde cero, gracias